# Ideal config for nginx rate limiting

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, rate-limiting

I am trying rate limitting using nginx. I have done rate limiting 25k rpm from a single server. My Current burst config is 5

When we are running 30k rpm for load test, can see 10-15k request dropped by limiter. I am thinking to increase burst value please suggest ideal burst value for this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ideal value, it totally depends of your configuration and how fast your server and application processing incoming requests. Because NGINX actually tracks requests at millisecond granularity.

Namely how quickly free slots will be released in the queue. See this [article](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/) for details.

I suggest you to measure not in requests per minute but in requests per second. Then you can choose the right burst value.

Comment: Thanks, yeah few of the articles helped me to understand how it’s working.

Comment: `Because NGINX actually tracks requests at millisecond granularity.` - I'm confused by the meaning of requests at millisecond granularity. Lets take an example: 1) 1 r/s - does this mean 1 request per 1000ms or do I need to further divide to get what is the capability at 1 ms?; 2) Another example - 10r/s - does this mean 1 request per 100ms? or do I need to further divide to get the value for 1 millisecond?

Comment: @variable as per article above, 
Rate – Sets the maximum request rate. In the example, the rate cannot exceed 10 requests per second. NGINX actually tracks requests at millisecond granularity, so this limit corresponds to 1 request every 100 milliseconds (ms). Because we are not allowing for bursts (see the next section), this means that a request is rejected if it arrives less than 100ms after the previous permitted one.